# Calculating average in Excel based on weekday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I need help in excel formula that calculates the average on specific days

I am currently getting error in this

```
=AVERAGE(IF(H2:H256)="Monday",J2:J256)
```

please help so that I can calculate only average where H columns has Monday

Comment: First, can you post some sample data. Second, your if statement looks wrong. Generally you would have: IF(H2:H256)="Monday",J2:J256,ELSEAREA)

Comment: You have your `)` in the wrong place: `=AVERAGE(IF(H2:H256="Monday",J2:J256))`  Also this is an Array formula.  It needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter.

Comment: Thanks it works :)

Comment: Seeing @David's answer, I would use that as it is not an array formula.

Comment: Thanks Scott yes both ways works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the averageif function as below

```
=averageif(H2:H256,"Monday",J2:J256)
```